# Creating visual studio template projects

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I created a project template as described here: [vs create template](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates) When I created a new project using the template, source files haven't added to project. 
I am using visual studio 2017 community edition. Actually source files (.h and .cpp) are visible in the solution explorer but they are not included in the project folder. So when I try to open them, ide gives me this message: "The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved."

 Is this a bug ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you try to re-install VS to fix it?

Comment: Nope :) I fixed it. I'll post how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a bug. I solved it like this: 
Visual studio automatically generates a .zip file containing the template project settings. However in that .zip folder, it doesn't include source files. I manually added every source files to the zip. Then I added fallowing lines to the automatically generated "MyTemplate.vstemplate" file.

```
<TemplateContent>
    <Project File="yourProjectName">
        <ProjectItem>source.cpp</ProjectItem>  
        .
        .
        .
    </Project>
</TemplateContent>
```

and it worked.